# How to get Commit ID of secondary source in CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a Codepipeline where in one of the stages I use CodeBuild to collect Commit IDs of multiple sources.

[image: These are the two input artifacts]

[image: Primary source]

I can get the commit ID of the primary source using `CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION` environment variable in codecommit. How do I get the commit id of the second source? Please help

Comment: Can you just use regular `git` commands?

Comment: @Marcin you're right. I should probably just do that. Still, would be nice if there was already one...thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the commit IDs for all your source actions using the [list_pipeline_executions](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codepipeline.html#CodePipeline.Client.list_pipeline_executions) command. It provides you with a list of CodePipeline execution summaries, where the first result is the latest execution. Each summary has a `sourceRevisions` attribute which looks like this for GitHub sources:

```
{
    "actionName": "Action name",
    "revisionId": "Commit ID",
    "revisionSummary": "Commit Message",
    "revisionUrl": "Link to the commit details page"
}
```

If your pipeline is likely to be running concurrently, make sure you get the current execution ID first so things do not get mixed up. You can do this with a one-liner in CodeBuild as suggested [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=753054).